# getting a data from html table and then using it further

Tags: jsp

I am thinking of creating a forum and i am using jsp for this ...basically
 i  wanted that whenever someone posts a question and subject ,the subject should appear in a table with his name and whenever someone is interested in the question by clicking that question he should be able to reach that specific question(as we do in this forum).but i am not able to do so ..since i am not able to get the logic of retrieving the data from an html table ...pls somebody suggest me..
thanxs in advance

Comment: use jquery to retrieve the values of the table elements,den use jquery again to set the values retrieved to a hidden field in a form and den send this form to the appropriate action...

Comment: I will put it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use Jquery to retrieve the values of the table elements.Then use jquery again to set the values retrieved to a hidden field within a form and then send this form to the appropriate action.

This is one of the easiest ways to do it using hidden field

Comment: i did the same as you said sir but when i am retreving value of hidden field I am getting null ,instead of the value. $(function(){
this is my jquery              
            $("tr").click(
            function ()
            {
               var $row = $(this);
               $("#text1").val($row.find(':nth-child(1)').text());
        
       

            }

              );


           }
         
          
);

Comment: <input type ="hidden" id="text1" name="txt" > thanxs in advance

Comment: @user3440711 in your action page u need to request the name not the id,so in your case `request.getParameter("txt");`

Comment: my problem is solved sir thanxs a lot :) god bless you